# R: Sum all rows that share at least the same TRUE values as current row

Tags: r

Here's a simplified version of the data set I have (the real one has 18 columns and 1000+ rows):

```
  col1  col2  col3   n
1 true  false false  50
2 true  true  false  30
3 true  false true   10
4 true  true  true   2
```

What I want to do is have row level sums that add up the n values for the rows that have *at least* the same columns as true. Like this:

```
  col1  col2  col3   n   sum
1 true  false false  50  82
2 true  true  false  30  32
3 true  false true   10  12
4 true  true  true   2   2
```

Any suggestions how to do this? It's been a while since I've last dabbled R so I'm a little lost...

EDIT: Added and extra example row. All rows have a unique combination of trues and falses if that matters.

Comment: Is it safe to assume your `col1, ... coln` values are `logical` class, not `character` class, despite their unusual lowercase appearance in your question?

Comment: Yes sorry, I wasn't sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the first part of your matrix and do a matrix multiplication with the n-row. Please keep in mind, that the values must be logical for this to work. You'd need to convert your "true" and "false" to T and F or 1 and 0.

```
testdata <- matrix(c(T, F, F, 50,
                     T, T, F, 30,
                     T, T, T, 2),
                   nrow  = 3,
                  byrow = T)

colnames(testdata) <- c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'n')
result <- data.frame(testdata)
result$sum <- t(testdata[, c(1:3)]) %*% testdata[, 4] 
result
  col1 col2 col3  n sum
1    1    0    0 50  82
2    1    1    0 30  32
3    1    1    1  2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that solution proposed by 'tester' isn't general enough: will crash for more rows (and data is said to be 1000+ x 18 cols). Maybe solution below is not the quickest (since not vectorized) and not the cleanest, but for 1000+ rows will be fairly enough. Please confirm that I correctly understood you with desired output (esp. row 6, which is T,F,T). Dplyr assumed, as well as conversion 0-1 to T/F is not a problem.
Regards!

EDIT: Changed solution according to comment, pls check.

```
library(dplyr)
testdata <- matrix(c(T, F, F, 50,
                     T, T, F, 30,
                     T, T, F, 30,
                     T, T, F, 30,
                     T, T, F, 30,
                     T, F, T, 30,
                     T, T, T, 2),
                   ncol  = 4,
                   byrow = T)

colnames(testdata) <- c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'n')
result <- data.frame(testdata)

result$sum = seq_len(nrow(result)) %>% lapply(.,
          function(i){
            x = data.frame(result[i,])[,grepl('col',colnames(result))] # select row and accordind columns
            tmp = x[x[,colnames(result)[grepl('col',colnames(result))]] %>% lapply(.,function(y) { y> 0 }) %>% unlist] # create temp non-zero one-row-df
            tmp %>% left_join(result) %>% select (n ) %>% sum # join with main table and sum
          }
) %>% unlist
result
  col1 col2 col3  n sum
1    1    0    0 50 202
2    1    1    0 30 122
3    1    1    0 30 122
4    1    1    0 30 122
5    1    1    0 30 122
6    1    0    1 30  32
7    1    1    1  2   2
```

Comment: I should've maybe added more example rows to my data set to better explain the desired result. Here it seems like we are calculating based on the number of true values? But those true values need to also be in the same columns. This means that for row 6 the sum should be 32 (adding up 6 and 7). For the other rows the numbers are correct.